# How to correctly return a file to a view?

Tags: jquery, post, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm having hard time achieving a supposedly easy task, and I don't understand if I'm doing something wrong or I have to look for the issue somewhere else. Basically I have my javascript POST request:

```
    $.ajax(
        {
            url: "/upload",
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
                stopUpdatingProgressIndicator();
            }
        }
    );
}

var intervalId;

function startUpdatingProgressIndicator() {
$("#progress").show();
$.post(
    "/upload/progress",
    function (progress) {

    }
);
```

and in my controller I'm serving the file in this way:

```
return File(fileMod, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, "test.mod");
```

But nothing happened, no file is presented for download, fileMod is a simple byte array, and no error is shown..

**EDIT**
I also tried to set the content type to **'application/force-download`** in my **'return file'** with no success.

Comment: In which action the `return File` exists? If you're returning file directly from AJAX POST, it's not possible (you must use GET action to download it).

Comment: If you're returning a file to an ajax request (either GET or POST) then the ajax request receives the file, not the browser, so you won't get a 'download prompt' as it's stored in `data` in `success:function(data)` - you need to add some javascript within `success:` to tell the browser to prompt to save it.

Comment: Easiest option is to open the the download action via a url to a new browser window/tab - the window will show a progress bar and auto-close when the file has downloaded.  May not fit your scenario though.

Comment: @freedomn-m many thanks for your reply! can you provide a little example as answer? to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get browser to prompt user to save a file dynamically generated by server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714631/how-do-i-get-browser-to-prompt-user-to-save-a-file-dynamically-generated-by-serv)

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897619/using-html5-javascript-to-generate-and-save-a-file/4551467#4551467

Comment: ``Return file to a view?`` How about creating url which just starts downloading this file? or if it is image then using it in <img src="url">

Comment: @Joelty I'm trying to do that right now...can you provide a good example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's example of very-simple controller action that loads file info from database (path, name, etc...) and then loads from disk that file.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult DownloadFile(Guid fileId)
{
    var file = _context.Files.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == fileId);

    if (file == null)
    {
        return ...
    }

    // you may also want to check permissions logic
    // e.g if (!UserCanDownloadFiles(user)) { return ... }

    var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file.PhysicalPath)); // add error handling here
    return new FileContentResult(bytes, "application/octet-stream") { FileDownloadName = file.FriendlyName }
}
```

Phyiscal Path = e.g `C:\AppFiles\file.jpg`

FriendlyName = e.g `file.jpg`

You may need to read about it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type

Sample download:

```
<a class="text-info" href="@Url.Action("DownloadFile", "MyController", new { fileId = item.Id })">Download</a>
```